# online radio, streaming audio

Tags: php, codeigniter, streaming

My customer has a website (developed with php using codeigniter frame-work) and want his users to listen radio (owned by customer) direct from the website. Someone mentioned something Ustream to me and am completely unaware of it. How can i build that will enable people to listen radio from a website? any online resource that can help me get started?

Thanx in advance..

Comment: Is it supposed to be actual radio that streams music in real time? or just basically music player?

Comment: yeah, thats what customer wants..

Comment: your answer didn't quite tell me much as i asked 2 questions. Either way i think answer by @egfx is the solution you're looking for. Cause live streaming or not, the result is pretty much the same unless you wanna run more or less "real" radioshow..

Comment: the users are supposed to hear as it hapens in radio program "real radioshow"

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need. I have no idea about how easy it would be to stream this straight from a website as i think you normally would need desktop audio player that can stream music from the internet. But, this might get you somewhere.. http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools

Comment: thanx..that helped a lot but u might want to check [link]ustream.tv[/link], they let u create account and give you some code to embed in your website from there u can broadcast live from your computer.

Comment: In that case that might be your number one choice. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think Ustream is the best option for a radio like experience. I'm assuming your looking for a radio like experience in the form of a auto-playing, randomizing, auto-looping playlist that will hold Mp3 files. You would want to go with a flash player with high customization potential like JW player or Flow player. here is a streaming plugin for Flow:

http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/audio.html

Comment: flash player nowadays is so obsolete, this answer needs a was up to go with the current times

Answer (score 1):

I have also been researching this.

If you want to avoid 'reinventing the wheel', you might try streaming through an audio player like those available here: http://www.listen2myradio.com/radio-streaming-free.php

*P.S. I only just came across this site, do some research around their distribution policy and any other conditions.*

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. You may notice this question is several years old (but still, thank you for leaving help for others. I took a moment to clean up the format of your answer so that is easier to read, especially for those who may not be fully fluent in English colloquialisms  Have an upvote :).